# Batch script to copy folder to all XP computers in domain

Tags: batch-file

Im trying to create a batch file that will copy a folder to all the computers in the domain if they are running windows XP.  I have this:

```
for /f "Tokens=1 delims=$" %a in ('dsquery * domainroot -limit 300 -filter "(&(objectCategory=computer)(operatingSystem=Windows XP*))"^| dsget computer -samid^|find /V "samid" ^| find /V "dsget"') do ( robocopy \\fserver\programs\ "\\%a\C$\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\" /s /R:1 /W:1)c
```

The problem is that a space is added before the computer name in the copy to location when I run it.
For example:

```
Error accessing Destination Directory \\ HP-0D9F\C$\Doc...
```

How do i get rid of the space?

Answer (score 1):

If you change your `dsquery` a bit you can remove the extra space. This also eliminates having to use `dsget` and the extra `find` so it seems to run a bit faster. This command will query the domain for all Windows XP computers, retrieve the "name" of each computer, filter the result to remove the column heading from the output, and print the name of each computer.

```
for /f %i in ('dsquery * domainroot -limit 300 -filter "(&(objectcategory=computer)(operatingsystem=Windows XP*))" -attr name ^| find /v /I "name"') do @echo %i
```

Now, just add in your robocopy command after the `do` you can run this as a one line command and avoid having to make a batch file.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove space, but this will have to be done across separate lines, so realistically you need to do this in a batch file

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "Tokens=1 delims=$" %%a in ('dsquery * domainroot -limit 300 -filter "(&(objectCategory=computer)(operatingSystem=Windows XP*))"^| dsget computer -samid^|find /V "samid" ^| find /V "dsget"') do (
set pc=%%a
set pc=!pc:\\ =\\!
robocopy \\fserver\programs\ "\\!pc!\C$\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\" /s /R:1 /W:1
)
```

It may be possible to concatenate the commands using `&&`'s but I haven't done any testing to know if it will work with delayed expansion, maybe look at using `cmd /v:on` if you really want it on one line.

Comment: It is still including the space.